# Unable to send confirmation email to subscribers

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, email, newsletter

when I subscribe for newsletter after that a subscription email should sent but I am not getting that email but user are added in subscriber list on admin side. And nor the notification of   thank you for subscription. what maybe possible issue ?

Comment: Is this the issue only with newsletter emails?Are you receiving other emails like Sales Order, Registration emails etc.?Did you check your email configuration settings in magento admin side?

Comment: @ShireenN which configuration ?   Account registration one I am getting emails and forget password  reset. but suddenly  I am not getting New subscriber notification on home page that "thank you for subscription"  and No email as well  can you have a look at site   consumer.jblashes.com   ?

Comment: @Learner you found any fix?

Answer (score 2):

Did you check the newsletter configuration? If you are using the magento 2 custom theme, it may override the email template.
[image]

Comment: yes my configurations are same. Even I am not getting subsriber issue on after subscribe to newsletter. can you have a look on site ?  onsumer.jblashes.com

Comment: To send confirmation email That you have subscribed to list. I need to create a new newsletter etc ?

Comment: I can't access your website http://onsumer.jblashes.com/ . Can you switch back to the Luma theme and try to subscribe again?

Comment: Did you get order success email or register email? If you get that email, you can debug in this method `vendor/magento/module-newsletter/Model/Subscriber.php:659`

Comment: you found any fix i am facing same issue